# Ignoring files/folders with crosswalk + cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ant, npm, node-modules

I'm using crosswalk for an android app as per [this guide](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html).

While developing only with cordova (no xwalk), I could ignore certain files and folders on build by using `aapt.ignore.assets` in the `ant.properties` config file, to exclude the files that I didn't want packaged - i.e. `node_modules`. When using crosswalk this file is completely ignored for me.

In the build process the .dotfiles are automatically excluded, but as per npm specifications the `node_modules` folder cannot be renamed in any way. There are a few files that I wouldn't like to package on every build, especially since the build fails if the `node_modules` is included, throwing me this error:

```
/mypath/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/mypath/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:950: null returned: 1
...
/mypath/release-multi/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
```

Currently while I develop I've gotta remove and re-add the folder every time I have to test a build and it's a complete hassle.

Any other while to forcefully exclude a list of files on build? I'm not an android dev -- currently only working with webapps.

Comment: Did you find a solution finally ?